# Error 403 while using GitHub API - Python - Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, github, http-status-code-403, github-api

I'm trying to build a product which requires users to login with GitHub. I have registered the product with GitHub and have got the client id and client secret.

I wrote code to fetch details of users as well as the repositories of the user.

Sometimes the code works properly and gives me the details that I need (user info and repositories details.) Sometimes I get Error : 403.

Below is the error I see in Google App Engine logs.

```
GET /users/Rishikesh45/repos HTTP/1.1" 403 None
```

Below is the code that I wrote.

```
class Authorization(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'ProductName'
        }

        url_queries = self.request.GET
        state = url_queries['state']
        code = url_queries['code']
        url = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_ID&redirect_uri=https://*****.appspot.com/authorization&scope=user,public_repo&code='+str(code)
        req = requests.post(url,headers=headers)
        req = str(req.content)
        access_token = ""
        i=13
        while(req[i]!='&'):
            access_token = access_token + req[i]
            i = i + 1

        user_api_url = 'https://api.github.com/user?access_token='+str(access_token)
        user_json_data = requests.get(user_api_url,headers=headers)
        userdata = json.loads(user_json_data.content)

        #Now I will have access to user data.

        #Below is the code to access repo data of the user

        #repos_url = userdata['repos_url']

        #This is what repos_url contains :  https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/repos

        res = requests.get(repos_url,headers=headers) -** Is this line correct?
        response_code = res.status_code
        if(response_code != 200):
            self.response.out.write(str(response_code)+" Something's wrong!")
            return
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Worked!")
```

The above code is a main chunk of the whole code. This code sometimes gives output as 'Worked' and sometimes as '403 Something's wrong!'

Why am I sometimes getting 403 error?

Comment: The API response will typically include a human-friendly message explaining the error (e.g., https://developer.github.com/v3/#failed-login-limit). Can you share the message that is included in the 403 response that you're getting?